# Is there a Java “Pet Store” reference app for cloud/microservices?

Tags: web-apps, web-services, cloud-service

Back in the early days of Enterprise Java and .NET, we often had reference apps to demonstrate how to build a complete multi-tier system (web app, app tier, database, etc), and to compare the different platforms. For example, Oracle still provides the [Java Pet Store](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/index-136650.html).

Does something like this exist for modern cloud/microservices apps? It doesn't need to be Java -- in fact, something like Node.js or Golang would be preferred -- however, it would be great if it demonstrated common needs like containers, logging, RPC, queuing, and databases. I'm also interested in anything that is either specific to given cloud providers (AWS, Azure, GCE, etc), or, even more interesting, neutral and portable between them.

I'm mostly interested in comparing the programming models, but eventually it would be nice to use this as a benchmark for performance, scale, and cost too.